# while loop is not running correctly according to condition set

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a list of sentences I need the code to break down into smaller phrases multiple times using 4 iterations starting from the first word

Example the sentence is: I am a man and I am 12 years old

I need the program to convert this to:

```
I
I am
I am a
I am a man
```

end of first cycle with 4 iteration, proceed to 2nd word

I am able to get the first part by writing a separate function called new_sen1 which has no issue. My second function does not run correctly. Here is my code:

```
sen = 'I am a man and I am 12 years old'

def new_sen2(sen):
    split_sen = sen.split()
    x = ' '
    y = 0
    i = 0
    num_list = [0]
    
while num_list[-1] < 5:
    split_sen.pop(0)
    num_list.append(i)
    while y < 5:
        new_sen = x.join(split_sen[0:y])
        print(new_sen)
        y += 1
    i += 1
```

The result I got was:

```
am
am a
am a man
am a man and
```

Why doesn't my while loop continue running for another 4 more times as specified by the condition? All help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I think you haven't posted the full code. `num_list` is undefined in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long explanation so bear with me.

I'm assuming your calling 'new_sen2' as a sort of initialization.

```
def new_sen2(sen):
split_sen = sen.split() # split_sen is a list of strings from sen split by space
x = ' '                 # x is a str of space
y = 0                   # y is int 0
i = 0                   # i is int 0
num_list = [0]          # num_list is a list with one element which is int 0
```

I will expand out you while loop within the while loop 5 times so its easy to understand.

```
while num_list[-1] < 5:                 # 1st iteration num_list[-1] = 0 which is <5
split_sen.pop(0)                        # remove first element in split_sen, which is 'I'
num_list.append(i)                      # add 'I' to new_list. nw_list now = [0, 'I']

while y < 1:                            # 1st iteration y = 0 which is < 1
    new_sen = x.join(split_sen[0:y])    # new sen = join split_sen[0:0] which equals '' (empty string)
    print(new_sen)                      # prints empty string
    y += 1                              # add 1 to y, y = 1

while y < 2:                            # 2nd iteration y = 1 which is < 2
    new_sen = x.join(split_sen[0:y])    # new sen = join split_sen[0:1] which equals 'am'
    print(new_sen)                      # prints 'am' string
    y += 1                              # add 1 to y, y = 2

while y < 3:                            # 3rd iteration y = 2 which is < 3
    new_sen = x.join(split_sen[0:y])    # new sen = join split_sen[0:2] which equals 'am a'
    print(new_sen)                      # prints 'am a' string
    y += 1                              # add 1 to y, y = 3

while y < 4:                            # 4th iteration y = 3 which is < 4
    new_sen = x.join(split_sen[0:y])    # new sen = join split_sen[0:3] which equals 'am a man'
    print(new_sen)                      # prints 'am a man' string
    y += 1                              # add 1 to y, y = 4

while y < 5:                            # 5th iteration y = 4 which is < 5
    new_sen = x.join(split_sen[0:y])    # new sen = join split_sen[0:3] which equals 'am a man and'
    print(new_sen)                      # prints 'am a man and' string
    y += 1                              # add 1 to y, y = 5
    
i += 1                                  # add 1 to i, i = 1
```

It then goes back to the outer while loop and will cause an TypeError because `num_list[-1] = 'I'` which cant be compared to 5. So your program stops there.

You could do this instead:

```
for i in range(len(sen_split)-3):
    for j in range(1, 5):
        print(' '.join(sen_split[i:i+j]))
```

The output for this is:

```
I
I am
I am a
I am a man
am
am a
am a man
am a man and
a
a man
a man and
a man and I
man
man and
man and I
man and I am
and
and I
and I am
and I am 12
I
I am
I am 12
I am 12 years
```

Comment: hi @newToCoding, thanks for providing me a more readable code! Actually, I wasn't trying to append the individual strings into num_list, but to keep the while loop running for 4 iterations so that I can run the iteration 4 times (should've been 6 actually, I miscalculated therefore the condition should've been num_list[-1] < 7). This is why i += 1 is also part of the while code. Whereas the while y < 5 code is to make sure that each iteration only prints out the number of words I wanted in each iteration. But I couldn't figure out why my code only returned me 1 iteration instead of 4.

Answer (score 2):

```
sen = 'I am a man and I am 12 years old' #initial sentence (a)
convert_sen = sen.split(" ")             #convert (a) to list = (b)
len_of_convert_sen= len(convert_sen)     #determine length of (b)
item_in_convert_sen = 1                  #initialise variable for iteration
while item_in_convert_sen < len_of_convert_sen:
    word = convert_sen[:item_in_convert_sen]
    convert_to_str =" ".join(map(str, word))
    print(convert_to_str)
    item_in_convert_sen +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your excpected output was, but maybe this code is what you wanted:

```
sen = 'I am a man and I am 12 years old'

sen=sen.split(" ")
for i_word in range(len(sen)):
    for l in range(i_word+1,min(i_word+5,len(sen))):
        print(" ".join(sen[i_word:l]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go about this would be to split the sentence string into a list, and then printing out one words at a time, increasing in each for-loop.

This could be done by

```py
sen = 'I am a man and I am 12 years old'
words = sen.split()

for i in range(5):
    print(" ".join(words[:i]))
```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and verify the answer if you found it useful, so that it's easy for others to get help quickly...